# Sharedpreferences: can't get the saved value updated in separate methods

Tags: android

I am writing a game app where I need to save the best score and get it back next time a user plays it. So saving happens when the player dies and retrieving (Read) happens when the game starts again: both are in separate methods.

Save:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences(HIGH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
prefsEditor.putInt(HIGHSCORE, best);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

Read:

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = getContext().getSharedPreferences(HIGH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int highestScore = myPrefs.getInt(HIGHSCORE, 1);
best=highestScore;
```

As you can see the default value when the `highestscore` is retrieved is 1. But I always end up getting 1! So may be the saving is not happening correctly. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Add a log statement to check what `commit()` returns -` true` or `false` ? If it's true, then it is sure that the values are saved successfully but if it's false, then it's not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! You were right, the commit() wasn't getting executed as the control was never entering the loot it was in. Now it's settled.